# Regex to extract headings and sub-headings from a pdf file using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a pdffile, using pdfplumber , I have extracted all the text from it. Then I need to find all headings and sub-headings from this text. I want to use the headings and sub-headings to extract the text within those headings and sub-headings.

My headings looks  like  1. heading one 2. heading two  3. heading three  4.  heading head four is and so on - they can have maximum 5 words

My subheadings looks like  same as heading  like 1.1  heading one of one  1.2 heading two of one  2.1  heading one of two  3.2  heading two of three and so.   I am not able to do it.   I tried following but did not work  , it worked only partially ,it could find some of the heading but no sub headings

```
import re
# Define the pattern
pattern = r'^\s*\d+(\.\d+)?\. ((?:\b\w+\b\s*){1,5})'
# Find all matches in the text
matches = re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```

and I want all the headings and sub headings to be returned in a list as mentioned above

Here is sample input data:

```
text= """
lotsf text text text 

1. Heading one
lots of text lots of text lots of text lot of text
123 456 text text2
0 10 text

1.1 subheading one of one

lot of text lots of text text is all
lot of text.
text and text.

1.2 subheading two of one

i m a ML enginner
i work in M
i do work in oracle also

2. Heading two

text again again text more text
holding on
backup and recovery

2.1 subheading one of two please

text text text text text

2.2 subheading two of two is

text or numbers
10  text 6345

2.3 subheading there of two

000 text 34
0 devices 
so many phone devices
""""
```

and expected output is :

```
[ 1. Heading one , 1.1 subheading one of one , 1.2 subheading two of one,2. Heading two,2.1 subheading one of two please,2.2 subheading two of two is,2.3 subheading there of two]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it can't find the subheadings is `(\.\d+)?\.` the regex requires always having a dot after the heading number(s) and your example subheaders don't have a dot after the second number (its not `1.1.` its just `1.1`). To fix this edit regex to `^(\d+\.\d* (?:\w+ *){1,5})`

- First expand `()` to surround everything you want
- Remove unnecessary part of regex: `\s*`, `\b`
- Change digit part to `\d+\.\d*` to accept major/minor headings

Comment: Hi @deppem Thank you. If I make the above change, I am also getting the patterns like 1 sometext   2  sometext , which I do not want or I want to exclude.  and yes  i am able to get 2.1  heading one of two lines when I made the above change. can you please advise.

Comment: even if you suggest 2 different pattern to handle heading and subheadings that should be fine.  and I want to the number 1  2  3 4 also come through in the output of findall above

Comment: @Ajeet if you could provide more input examples of what you have and what you want vs don't a better regex can be provided

Comment: @deppem thanks .  please find below the data lotsf text text text 

1. Heading one
lots of text lots of text lots of text lot of text
123 456 text text2
0 10 text

1.1 subheading one of one

lot of text lots of text text is all
lot of text.
text and text.

1.2 subheading two of one

i m a ML enginner
i work in M
i do work in oracle also

2. Heading two

text again again text more text
holding on
backup and recovery

Comment: the second part of data2.1 subheading one of two please

text text text text text

2.2 subheading two of two is

text or numbers
10  text 6345

2.3 subheading there of two

000 text 34
0 devices 
so many phone devices


I need output as  [ 1. Heading one , 1.1 subheading one of one , 1.2 subheading two of one,2. Heading two,2.1 subheading one of two please,2.2 subheading two of two is,2.3 subheading there of two]

Comment: sorry if data is not coming formatted.  as comment does not allow me to put everything in one go

Comment: add examples to OP, formatted too

Comment: Hi , the output expected is I need output as  [ 1. Heading one , 1.1 subheading one of one , 1.2 subheading two of one,2. Heading two,2.1 subheading one of two please,2.2 subheading two of two is,2.3 subheading there of two]

Comment: @Ajeet edit your original question with the examples of what should match and examples of what shouldn't match

Comment: I did edit the question to include input data and output needed.

Comment: thanks so much. worked like a charm on my real data as well. not able to voteup as i don't have required  reputations orr something. but this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: for everyone's benefit - the problem discussed here and solution discussed is part of a larger problem which many of us face - how to extract paragraphs of text from pdf - there is no one good solution to it. so i have taken this approach - get the headings and sub headings and then I have used another regex to get the text under that heading or sub heading. if you like this approach - please upvote it. I need it.

Answer (score 0):

it should be posible in the shell without any more than pdftotext to do most of the text task.

`pdftotext input.pdf output.txt`

you say give per example

```
lotsf text text text

etc...
```

so if a second command is in windows (or similar in nix sed)

`type output.txt |findstr /R "^[0-9]\." >headings.txt`

we get a file with the headings

```
1. Heading one
1.1 subheading one of one
1.2 subheading two of one
2. Heading two
2.1 subheading one of two please
2.2 subheading two of two is
2.3 subheading there of two
```

now it gets slightly harder as you want [ item 1., item2, item3 ]

so the closest to that is

`@echo [>list.txt&&@for /f "tokens=*" %f in (headings.txt) do @echo/|@set /p=%f, >>list.txt`

followed by `echo ]>>list.txt`

result

```
[
1. Heading one,  1.1 subheading one of one,  1.2 subheading two of one,  2. Heading two,  2.1 subheading one of two please,  2.2 subheading two of two is,  2.3 subheading there of two, ]
```

So windows console commands often cause two very minor problems

1. I should have tried to remove the initial line feed and
2. there is a loop final `,` where one would normally not add one but for CSV that's usually not a problem.

so all that could be a 4 line.cmd file for "drag and drop" any pdf and instantly output a structured list for downstream editing in python or notepad or use as bookmarks in source PDF.

potential batch file (will need tweaking for a user set of locations)

dropMeApdf2LIST.cmd (needs slightly different structure to command lines)

```
@echo off
"path to poppler\bin\pdftotext.exe" -enc UTF-8 -nopgbrk "%~1" "%~dpn1.txt"
type "%~dpn1.txt" |findstr /R "^[0-9]\." >"%~dpn1-headings.txt"`
echo [>"%~dpn1-list.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ("%~dpn1-headings.txt") do @echo/|@set /p=%%f, >>"%~dpn1-list.txt"  
echo ]>>"%~dpn1-list.txt"
notepad "%~dpn1-list.txt"
```

so drop this page as a pdf onto that file gives me this, and humorously includes my list of 1. and 2. above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @KJ , I should have mentioned that I needed to do it  in python.  Thank you for all your inputs and effort in helping with an answer. really appreciate it.